# jihadists the world over

Tags: modifiers

> He's been described as "an inspiration" to jihadists **the world over**, but this morning 29-year-old Australian man Musa Cerantonio is languishing in a jail cell in the Philippines. ([Aussie ABC](http://www.abc.net.au/am/content/2014/s4044735.htm))

What does the highlighted phrase mean? Does it modify the previous noun, *jihadists*, and meaning: *in the world that is over there*?

Comment: "the world over" can often be used to mean "all over the world" (i.e., "worldwide").

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a fixed phrase with two forms:

```
   all the world over
       the world over　　　　　(This version is more common.)
```

It's a literary postmodifier meaning "all over the world; everywhere; throughout the world".

Since it's a fixed phrase with rather unique grammar, we don't really need to analyze it.  But if we do so anyway, we might say something like this: The preposition ***over*** takes ***(all) the world*** as a complement, even though it comes afterwards instead of before.  This is unusual, but not unprecedented—it is similar to the preposition ***ago***.

Since the entire phrase is a postmodifier, it follows what it modifies.  In this case, that means it modifies the noun ***jihadists***.

It does not mean "in the world that is over there".

Comment: Thank you very much. After reading your answer, I now get yours in [Random House #24](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/over?s=t):”over -> through a region, area, etc.: He was known the world over.“

Comment: And I get your explanation, 'prepositions following their complement in PP structure, in CGEL (p.631-2). Thanks a lot.

Comment: It does **not** modify the noun! It modifies the prepositional phrase *to jihadists*.

Answer (score 3):

*The world over* is another way -now rather literary and clichéd- of saying *all over the world*, meaning “at places throughout the world”. It does modify *jihadists*.